# Nativescript Vue: How to get access to data properties inside of v-template?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have access to my data such as `lowText` inside the first Label element. But when I have inside the Pager component and inside the v-template, I don't have access to it.  How can I pass in the context of it?

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label :text="this.lowText" />
   <Pager for="item in items">
      <v-template>
         <Label :text="this.lowText" />
      </v-template>
   </Pager>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lowText` is a data attribute, you don't have to use `this.lowText`. Simply use `lowText`, that should work at both inside and outside v-template.

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label :text="lowText" />
   <Pager for="item in items">
      <v-template>
         <Label :text="lowText" />
      </v-template>
   </Pager>
</StackLayout>
```